# How do I disassemble this metal sliding-interlocking fastener on this chair?

Tags: wood-repair, fasteners

I've recently got two lovely wooden chairs, and I wanted to disassemble them to fix their wobble issues and to revamp some dings that the wood in the wood.

I'm stuck on figuring out how to detach these flush interlocking metal joints that they used to join the four legs., and are the main cause of the wobble. It looks like a simple sliding mechanism with two parts that screw into two different pieces of wood, and one slides into the other (see pictures). I've tried sliding the inner part out but it seems to be locked and it doesn't bulge (and I don't want to apply too much pressure and split the wood). I can't see any locking mechanism.

[image: The joint]

[image: From the side]

[image: From the bottom]

Any ideas on how I can detach these two pieces of wood?
(if it makes any difference, it is a dutch-made chair)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I'm not familiar with those (never even seen a pic of them previously) but it sure looks like a simple sliding mechanism from the photos. If it is, there are multiple reasons the two pieces could get stuck but regardless within reason you should be able to knock it apart without further damage to the wood. Use a hammer (the heaviest you have) and a block of sacrificial soft wood and tap on each end and see if you can get it to start moving in the obvious direction (upwards in image 1, down in 2). A squirt of WD-40 or similar into the mechanism should help.

Comment: In the 3rd image, it looks like there _may_ be a tab on the rail side of the connector, pointed at by the mold line on the leg part. You may need to put a flat blade screwdriver in there, pry it gently to the left, then tap down with your mallet to free the rail. Additionally, there is a split in the rail wood in that image, so be careful in your removal that you don't make that split worse, and plan to repair it once you've got the parts separated.

Comment: @FreeMan, I took that to be the side of a round-head screw that isn't fully tightened (or has worked loose).

Comment: Could be that, too, @Graphus. Dunno, it was a thought.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied! In the end, @Graphus was right. It turns out that sometimes all you need is some WD-40 and good old brute force.
The fastener came loose after a bit of convincing with a hammer, and thankfully the wood was not split or damaged further. Success! 
Thanks again for all your answers!

Comment: @JoshBruegger if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that this is a Question & Answer site, not a general discussion forum. Please write that up as an _answer_ (in the box below), then, as soon as the system will let you, click the check mark next to it. This will help others find the answer, as not everyone reads comments and they can get deleted.

Comment: Yes, bashy-bash-bash rather than tappy-tap-tap is usually the order of the day when something is stuck in a woodworking context :-) Do write that up as a self-Answer so you can have the points, and the badge.

Comment: I was able to remove the chair seat and then use a rubber hammer to bang the wooden pieces that had the fasteners on the ends. Can I buy replacement sliding interlocking fasteners. I have the same chair as the photo but I do not know the manufacturer. Some of my chairs have partly broken fasteners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who replied! In the end, @Graphus was right. It turns out that sometimes all you need is some WD-40 and good old brute force. The fastener came loose after a bit of convincing with a hammer, and thankfully the wood was not split or damaged further. Success!